# How to Update a real time ajax request for an animated circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, elasticsearch

so i'm using [gaugeMeter](https://github.com/Mictronics/GaugeMeter) to dynamically show the cpu usage of my elasticSearch Host ,
the values are showing fine but the animation of the gauge/circle it self is acting weird
instead of the indicator continuing the animation from the same position
it goes all back to 0.
for example lets say you're driving and as you accelerate the indicator accelerates along
in my case it goes back all way to 0 and reaches that value instead of continuing from the old value.
**Feels like im riding a broken car here**...

does it have something to do with using setInterval ?
if so how can i keep the old value and update based from it

```
function fetchdata(){
            $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?format=json",
            type:"GET",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data){

            var temp1 = data;

        $("#GaugeMeter_1").gaugeMeter({
            
            percent:data[0].cpu,
            text:data[0].cpu,
            text_size:1,
            width:7,
            animate_text_colors:true,
            animationstep:2,
            showvalue:true,
            animate_gauge_colors:true
            });
            }
            
            });
            }

            setInterval(fetchdata,1000);
```

Comment: You're fully re-creating the jquery plugin "gaugeMeter" every one second. The documentation page you linked to  has an example of how to update it, which you should use.

Comment: it will only update once you refresh the page with their given example

Comment: You want to call your gaugeMeter() initialize call only once, not in fetchdata, and you want to use the update command from the documentation in fechdata

Comment: $("#GaugeMeter_1").gaugeMeter({percent:temp1[0].cpu});
initialize it in jquery like this right ? but how about the data that comes from the ajax request 
its saying that cpu is undefined even tho i declared the temp1 variable globally and assigned the data to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix to this , i had to call the constructor only once outside  the fetchdata function and do only an update method of the values inside the fetchdata function